# Maven Dependencies not downloaded for the Jar artifact in local repository using archiva

Tags: eclipse, maven-3, pom.xml, archiva

I am trying to setup a organization wide maven repository. I have installed archiva as a service and added a mirror in my local settings.xml of maven to disable the maven central.

I have uploaded my project1's jar into archiva internal repository. I use the groupid, artifactid and version number of the project1's jar in my project2's POM.xml. I see that that project1's jar has been added into maven dependencies. But the project1's dependencies are not downloaded.

I created the jar for project1 using maven build (using goal as "package"). What changes are needed in project1's POM.xml or any other configuration to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was I was just uploading the jar. I was making a mistake of not uploading the POM.xml along with it. This resolved the issue for me.